How to find foreground apps in split screen mode in Android
I have been trying to find foreground app from a service, I use usage_stats permission to check for current running app. But the problem is when I use split screen mode it doesn't detect the app.
I tried to use usage stats every 100 milliseconds instead of one second, it still didn't detect apps opened from split screen mode.

can you post the required code part need to reproduce the problem ?
